# Add Multiple Data Sets/Sources to BIRT Report

Tags: dataset, report, birt, wizard

I'm currently working with BIRT and I am having problems trying to create a report with multiple data sources and data sets.

For example, let's say I have a wizard. This wizard allows the user to graphically select data sources in a list. After selecting a few data sources and finishing the wizard, I would like the report to be rendered with the selected data sources.

I have tried a few thing such as adding data sources/sets to an ElementFactory object, but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone know of where I can find documentation on this sort of thing? Possibly some pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to be able to select a variable number of data sources (so that one run might access seven data sources while another might only access two), or will there be a fixed number of them?

Comment: There is a list of 3 data sources to select. They can add multiple instances of these 3 data sources if they would like.